# Is there any difference between an article and a paper?

Tags: publications, terminology

Are papers and articles really different in academic context or they are same words for the published manuscripts in conferences or journals?

The only thing comes to my mind is that may be an article is un-academic synonym of a paper, and it is not often used in academic context. Articles may be the texts which are published in a magazine; a paper is more academic, it is published in academic journals.

Could you please tell me what is the difference and whether there is any special usage of each word in papers published in a branch of science or in a country?